# What is the square root of negative one raised to the power of square root of negative one?

Tags: complex-analysis

What is $\sqrt{-1}^\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: Do you know about branch cuts, in particular of the complex logarithm?

Answer (score 2):

$i^i=e^{i\log(i)}=e^{i(\log|1|+i\frac{\pi}{2})}=e^{-\pi/2}$

Comment: (I used the principal branch)

Comment: If we read the question carefully, the OP seems to have asked what is $\;\sqrt{i^i}\;$ ...

Comment: It actually says the square root of negative one raised to the power of square root of negative one, which could either mean $i^i$ or $\sqrt{(-1)^\sqrt{-1}}$.